# Bypassing the router doesn't work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wired-networking

So I'm trying to bypass my router, just for kicks.
I thought it'd be pretty easy, just connect the router-modem wire to the computer, and I did just that,  but I'm not getting an internet connection.

My usual setup:

- Incoming wire connected to a modem.
- Modem connected to a router.
- Router then connected to computers (either wireless or through wires, both work)

What I did:

- Found the wire connecting modem to router, unplugged it from the router and connected it to the computer.

The computer recognizes that I've switched to wired, '*identifies*' the connection, but fails to access the internet. That's weird, because **it's working perfectly well while using the router**.

While troubleshooting, it says "*Local Area Connection doesn't have a valid IP configuration.*"

Any ideas?

Comment: assuming that you have a separate modem and connection the wire comming out of the modem, it should work. When it doesn', maybe the network speed negotioation failed. It may help to set the network speed of your local adapter to 100mbit / full duplex (and if this doesn't work to 100mbit / half duplex). Before changing remember the original settings and set them back after testing.

Comment: Let me get this straight: wall to ISP's 'router', ISP's router to 'switch', 'switch' to computer? This should be the basic setup. What and how are you trying to bypass? If you connect the 'router's drop to computer - how is the computer still connected to switch - via a second NIC?

Comment: @arch-abit What I have usually is "wall to modem, modem to router, which then relays a wireless signal to all computers in range". This works, and I can even connect an ethernet cable from the router to the computer, and it still works. I want to bypass the router, connecting the modem wire directly into the computer. But I can't access the internet.

Comment: I though so, terminology and wired/wireless mix.

From wall to ISP is a ROUTER not a modem or a switch - it has DNS to record and hold, it should have DHCP, and it also has firmware to authenticate itself to the ISP's network. Your account and payment info is paired with this authnetication process so the ISP keeps your access open or close it. If you 'bypass' this router you end up without internet, period.

Your 'no local access' is an entirely different matter, it has to do with bypassing the ISP's router and loosing the DNS service inside of it. You still have IP but no DNS.

Comment: @arch-abit You don't know what you're talking about. It's completely possible to have a broadband modem that is just a pass-through modem with no authentication, no DNS, no NAT, no DHCP. This is not terribly rare on DSL.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting your cable modem directly to a PC is sometimes a necessary troubleshooting step - to ascertain whether problems are with your router or not, for example.

Assuming this is a cable modem, and that it behaves like mine: Cable modems will only recognize a single device behind it - if you want to share the connection, a router does that and is expected to be that single device.

Once it has recognized that single device, at least on mine, you have to power cycle it before switching the device it's connected to.  Disconnect modem, power cycle it, wait for it to come back up, then connect new device.

If it still doesn't work, you may need to set the MAC address of the NIC you are connecting to the cable modem to the same one as your router temporarily.

And when you are done on the PC and want to connect it back to the WAN port on the router, you'll need to power cycle it again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Sorry for the late reply, though, I've been busy. I've tried everything, power-cycling the modem, and changing the NIC's physical address to the one that my router has, but nothing seems to work! :(